# http://localhost:3000/localhost:5000/api/register when i request URL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

Hey Guys Im getting error on this COde About fetching the react server URL and node server URL How to solve this porblem
Guys can u check and send me solution for this Thank

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if your server URL exactly matches the URL pattern? Like `http://localhost:4001/*`. Because I also faced a similar issue where I put my URL as `http:localhost:4001/*` and this is how I resolved it.

Thanks